# Java, Simple XML parsing list

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

How can I parse this list in Java? I have `List<Image>` which returns from server, but I can't get a single item.

```
<images>
   <image>
       uploads/posts/2008-10/1225141003_1-21.jpg
   </image>
    <image>
       uploads/posts/2008-10/1225141003_1-22.jpg
   </image>
</images>
```

> @Root(name = "Images") public class Images {
>
> ```
> @ElementList(required=false, inline = true)
> private List<Image> imageList;
>
> public List<Image> getImageList() {
>     return imageList;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> @Root(name = "image") public class Image {
>
> //Some code.......
>
> }

Comment: what do you want to parse it into?

Comment: please, look on it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem in this way:

```
@Root(name = "images") 
public class Images {

     @ElementList(entry = "image", required=false, inline = true)
     private List<String> imageList;

     public List<String> getImageList() {
         return imageList;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    String total = "";
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total +=line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return total;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you are able to get that xml:

```
String responseXML = inputStreamToString(yourXMLResponseFromServer.getEntity().getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

To interpret XML files I have always used the org.w3c.dom.Document Interface which offers a Javascript like document modification. Check out the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) on the oracle website!

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM and Xpath

**1 Parse your String**

```
String xml="<my_xml/>";
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

**2 use an xpath**

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression="/images/image";
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression) ; 
NodeList nodes  = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document,  XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

**3 iterate**

```
for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k++)
    {
    Node nodeSegment = nodes.item(k);
    if (nodeSegment.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
        Element eElement = (Element) nodeSegment;
        System.out.println("TEXT CONTENT="+eElement.getTextContent());
```

**ALTERNATIVE:**

If you know you have 1 or 2 image (s):

```
expression="/images/image[1]"; // first one
String value = xPath.evaluate(expression, document);
System.out.println("EVALUATE:"+value);
```